# How can I construct a nilpotent matrix with the property $A^2 \not= 0$ but $A^3=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

An example of a matrix $A$ that has the property  $A^2=0$ would be $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

However, I can't seem to figure out a "formula" to construct a matrix that has the property $A^3=0$ but $A^2 \not = 0$. Or in general, a formula for a matrix that has the property $A^k=0$ with $A^{k-1} \not=0$. Does such a formula even exist?

Comment: You need bigger matrices for this. Try $3\times3$ upper triangular ones.

Comment: Like this: $\huge \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible in a space of dimension $\ge k$. In such a space take the matrix

$$N_k=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0& \dots&0\\
0&0&1& \dots&0\\
0&\vdots&\ddots& \ddots&0\\
0&0&\dots& 0&1\\
0&0&0& \dots&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So If I want to construct a nilpotent matrix that has the property $A^5=0$ but $A^4 \not=0$ I would have to start with a $5 \times 5$ upper triangular matrix?

Comment: Yes, you need in that case to have a space of dimension $5$ at least. And the matrice I provided is an example of a possible choice.

Comment: I don't think your formulation is correct, "space of dimension greather than or equal to $k$". What space is this? The vector space of $k\times k$ matrices has dimension $k^2$, not $k$. **Edit:** Also, naming that matrix $I_k$ is a bad idea.

Comment: I’m speaking of the vector space on which the matrices operate. Not the space of the matrices.

Comment: That vector space here is, arguably, either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, both of which have dimensions smaller than $3$.

Comment: @GitGud $\mathbb R $ or $\mathbb C$ is the field on which the vector space is built. Not the vector space itself.

Comment: I just reread what you wrote, sorry. The vector space on which the matrix operates, OK! I stand by my initial statement, though. Who has ever mentioned the space in which the matrix operates with this? Just the fact that I didn't understand this formulation should be telling something.

Answer (score 1):

Not that you asked, but it's easy to see that this is impossible for a $2\times 2$ matrix. Say $A$ is  $2\times2$ and $A^3=0$. If $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ then $\deg(p)\le 2$ (by Cayley-Hamilton) and $p(t)|t^3$; hence $p(t)|t^2$, so $A^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You already got answer but I am just adding one thing which will help to understand the process.

For n=2,
This linear transformation T(x,y)=(y,0) will give A nonzero but $A^{2}=0$.(perform linear transformation twice and you will see it and each LT is associated with matrix ,you will get matrix with that property.

Now for n=3,
T(x,y,z)=(y,z,0) will satisfy given conditions.(perform LT thrice).Find it's matrix.

You can get pattern.